# Trouble returning the customer object with stripe queries

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am playing around with stripe queries and in the documentation this is the example that is given:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('some-api-key');

const customer = await stripe.customers.search({
  query: 'metadata[\'foo\']:\'bar\'',
});
```

so naturally I tried this:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('some-api-key');

const customer = async () => await stripe.customers.search({
  query: 'metadata[\'foo\']:\'bar\'',
});

console.log(customer)
```

but all I get back is this in the console:

```
customer() {
            return _ref.apply(this, arguments);
        }
```

and when I try this I just get promise pending:

```
console.log(customer().then(data => console.log(data)));
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: One `console.log` is sufficient - remove the outer one, please. Try with this: `customer().then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)));`. The `JSON.stringify()` is used to make the `data` display-friendly (in case `data` is/has object/s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this:

```js
const customer = async () => await stripe.customers.search({
  query: 'metadata[\'foo\']:\'bar\'',
});
```

Then `customer` is an async function. So you have two ways to log the result: `console.log(await customer())` or `customer().then(res => console.log(res))`.